# RegEx to find the last part of an email address

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to get the last part of the email address so that I can run some if statements and do what I need to do. Ex. I need to make sure the email addresses end in yahoo.com. How can I go about finding that?

I am using reg ex like so to make sure they are valid.

```
string pattern = @"\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b";
Regex emailValid = new Regex(pattern);
```

Comment: Why not just a simple `.Split("@")`

Comment: If all you want is to check if it's Yahoo, why do you need regex? `email.ToUpper().EndsWith("@YAHOO.COM")`

Comment: @Mikael honestly, thats kinda what I was wondering. If i even needed to use regex. I will give this a shot and let you know how it works. thank you very much. Make this an answer and I will accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if it's a yahoo email, you can use:

```
email.ToUpper().EndsWith("@YAHOO.COM")
```

Note: If you're getting this email from raw user input you may want to throw a Trim() on there as well.

If you just absolutely want to use regex

```
string pattern = "@yahoo.com"
Regex.Match(
    input: email,
    pattern: pattern,
    options: RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```